# Microservices: datasource per instance or per microservice?

Tags: database, architecture, microservices

Building microservice architecture I faced the problem of data sharing between instances of the same microservice.

I have microservice, that massively uses it's datasource - every request to service cause database request (usually insert). This service will be used very heavily and I plan to hide multiple instances behind Load Balancer. And here rises a question: shall these instances use ONE database (will the database be a bottleneck?) or MULTIPLE (datasource per instance) have?

Comment: As a side note: Its better to use client side load balancing like Ribbon, instead of server side load balancing. You might want to check that out too :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my experience with mSOA architecture, I've never seen

> MULTIPLE (datasource per instance)

to be used. Even if you plan to load it heavily, the most common DBs by nature support multi-threading access. Usually the bottleneck (or slowest part) of a DB system is the disk. We had to scale our clusters several times (relatively cheap if you are in the cloud, but scalability can also become an issue, as more threads will be required to manage and execute the scaled DB system). Keep in mind that some RDBMS use a temporary DB (tempdb) that is used by all the DBs on that instance for sorting, hashing, temporary variables, etc. Multithreading and splitting up this tempdb files can be used to improve the throughput of the tempdb, thereby improving overall server performance.

Since now I work with [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/), I have to say that there are some corner cases, when your actions over one instance are not completely (and timely) synced. This causes access over resources to be denied (right after registration of the event) even after correct authentication.

> I plan to hide multiple instances behind Load Balancer

This is a proper design for your App servers, so utilizing a DB cluster should be suitable as well. Aiming at full answer - you can consider [DWH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse), in case you have a lot of services and you want to be able to do some data mining and analysis from all their DBs.

Answer (score 10):

Having one database instance per microservice instance is a very unusual architecture.  If you are concerned about load on the database, you could cluster it for higher throughput, however, inserts don't cause much load.

I'd suggest you look into a NoSQL database if you are concerned about the database being a bottleneck.  NoSQL databases are designed to scale better for high throughput and handle large amounts of data well.  Of course the downside is that they don't handle complex data models well.

Comment: "database instance per microservice instance is a very unusual architecture." But it is still recommended by popular people in this field!

Comment: On the contrary Using common DB for multiple services, is against the Micro-service ideology, which again creates the coupling between the services

Comment: @sschrass  are you sure that "database instance per microservice instance" is a recommended approach ?! can you provide a link.  I believe that database per (micro)service is the recommended approach.

Comment: Not directly, Sam Newman writes in his book about data pumps and EventDriven. With Kafka you get in-memory databases (RocksDB) that serve as source of state. And by exchanging events, there often is no need for additional databases at all.

Comment: A lot of this may depend on the type of data, but insisting that using a common database creates undesirable coupling isn't true.  I can create multiple services that each use the same database that are no more coupled than if they were using independent databases.  Each service locates the BD via config properties (such as env vars) and owns its own schema and/or tables and each is blissfully unaware that other services are accessing the same database.  That db can then be clustered if higher through-put is needed.

Comment: Without too much trouble, the services could also be broken into slammer groups, each group using its own db.  On the service perspective, the only thing that changed is the DB connection configuration.

Comment: @scchrass I would question that.. Database per microservice is how i’ve always understood it. Multiple instances can access the same database, just not “share” the schema and database with other services

Answer (score 4):

My approach would be a service local DB (read: datasource per instance). In memory or in the same Pod. To synchronize the at startup always fresh DB I would use Apache Kafka. As soon as the service begins initializing, it queries Kafka for all entries it is interested in (mind the *compact log*-Feature of Kafka, that only returns the recent state of an entity) populates its DB and begins serving requests.

This would increase startup time of course, but the benefit is, that the DB can be of any tech or scheme the service wants it to be (this could even change from version to version of the service). Also there is no need of an DB-Cluster, but you would need a properly configured Kafka-Service, but that could also be used for Event Sourcing among your services.

Answer (score 2):

A lot depends on your actual use case but I think write-behind or write-back could be one of your solution. [This](http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.10.0/html/ehc-all/index.html#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set/co-recipe_database_write_overload.html) link talks about the technique with EhCache, I think there should be other caches supporting the feature, you may want to google a bit on that.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on your scalability requirements, and how/if your microservice instances need to cooperate to provide a single result. It helps to know what the trade-offs are:

**Keeping it all in one database**

- Easier configuration
- No coordination or communication with other instances of your service
  needed
- Easier to discover your full dataset
- System performance limited by database performance

**Keeping the databases separate**

- The full answer for a request may be spread across microservice
  instances In that case you have increased communication and
  negotiation to resolve the request Handling data when you loose that
  microservice node (even when the database is still up, you can't get
  at it until a new one with the right configuration is stood back up)
- Increased configuration complexity